# Is there a good charting API that lazy-loads large data sets with Ajax on scroll/zoom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a JavaScript charting API that would permit querying the server with bounds on the horizontal and vertical axes to get new data points. Before you ask, the data set is mind-blowingly massive: there are ~300 million points.

Comment: You're talking about both a server side and client side component.  Most of the JavaScript based charting libraries I've seen are client side only.  Sure, they may support AJAX requests for data, but it's up to you to write server-side component.  Love to see if someone else has something for you though.

Comment: I'm happy to write the server-side component. return blah.subList(243870,244870) works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) is a pretty good looking charting library.  It does support zoom, and AJAX lookups.  I have a feeling you'll have some legwork to do to hook zoom events to do data updates, but can't say for sure as I haven't used HighCharts a whole lot.

Comment: @verve if it works for you... maybe post back a code sample? I'm curious :)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this presentation:
http://www.ted.com/talks/view/lang/en//id/129

Seadragon deals specifically with pixels similar to what you are asking about.

Comment: Also check out http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/SeadragonAjax which is the JavaScript version.

Comment: Interesting find, but unfortunately it won't help me. The data set is generated from user input, so I couldn't create a gallery of zooming images beforehand.

Comment: I remember seeing that TED talk some time ago, didn't realize that had released a JS lib. nice.

Comment: Instead of thinking of it as a pixel, think of it as a pointer to a data set. How you aggregate the data on zooming in and zooming out is the real challenge with user data. Without knowing what that specific data range is I cannot derive any better solutions. Your user data will have to, in some fashion regardless of API, be aggregated similar to mipmap http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap . After that server side step, something like SeaDragon could AJAX query some slice of that data. Let me know if you would like to know more on that path of thought.